# How can I disable mipmapping on textures loaded from .X files?

Tags: xna

I'm trying to render a plane mesh textured with a simple grid pattern. The problem is that XNA keeps mip-mapping the texture in horrible, horrible ways.

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to get this grid to look as close to vector graphics as possible (so anisotropic filtering is out of the question, I must use point filtering):

```
SamplerState ss = new SamplerState();
ss.Filter = TextureFilter.Point;
ss.MaxMipLevel = 0;
ss.AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Wrap;
ss.AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Wrap;
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = ss;
```

I'm loading the mesh, and it's textures, from an `.x` file so I don't have control over the specifics of the texture loads. Can I disable mip-mapping for the whole rendering process?

Comment: @childonline Not sure, off the top of my head. If it's not an option for the default content importer, you may need to write a content pipeline extension. Or maybe try doing this without a `.x` model? (Set up the vertices by hand and load the texture independently.)

Comment: (There may be a way to do it at runtime - but I'm not sure - I would have thought that `MaxMipLevel` would have worked. But I've never played with that.)

Comment: @Andrew Russell: Nevermind, I've fixed it, it's sort of a dirty hack, but i've set the MipMapLevelOfDetailBias of the SamlperState to -2, i don't know why it works, but it works. Here is a screen: http://imgur.com/OFbYAqE

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default content importer, there's no way to control the mipmap generation behavior of the textures.

The [`.x` file format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173015(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't really provide a template that allows control over mipmapping of textures, and XNA's importer assumes you'll want mipmaps for all the referenced textures.

Your two best options are likely:

- [Build a custom importer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447754.aspx) to parse the `.x` file and generate the textures *without* mipmaps.
- Ignore or discard the textures loaded by the content importer for the `.x` file, loading manual copies yourself, in which you disable mipmapping.
- Set the [`MipMapLevelOfDetailBias`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.samplerstate.mipmaplevelofdetailbias.aspx) property of your sampler state to a sufficiently-negative number to ensure mipmap level 0 is always used (in later shader models you could use [`SampleLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to explicitly specify that mipmap 0 should be sampled, but I don't think XNA supports a new-enough model for this).

The last option is probably the easiest, but also wastes all the memory of the extra mip levels which you'll never sample.